# MYSQL - Retrieve Results by Date Proximity

Tags: mysql, date, calendar, proximity

my question is:

assuming we have a calendar_table with UNIX datestamp date_column, i want retrieve the event with the closest proximity to the today date.

So, for example if there is no event today, keep the closest one based on it's date!

**UPDATED**

probably i need to be more clear, i need to retrieve not just one event, but All events in the table with the same date, closest to today date!

Thanks All you guys! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar_table` WHERE `date_column` = (SELECT `date_column` FROM `calendar_table` ORDER BY ABS(`date_column` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse! it's exactly what i was looking for! a subquery is just perfect! i have just switched to **ASC** and it work fine!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM `calendar_table`
ORDER BY ABS(`date_column` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: hi soulmerge, thank's for responce, i have one question, what if i need to keep All not just 1 of event with the same date!?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make select the difference between today's date and the event date, and select the smallest result.

First select the difference like this:
`SELECT DATEDIFF(EventDate, Now()) As Datediff FROM calendar`
or if you want to find events in the past as well:
`SELECT Abs(DATEDIFF(EventDate, Now())) As Datediff FROM calendar`

Then just order by that field and take the first one off the list.